# How to gracefully handle video streaming on low networks

Tags: android, error-handling, video-streaming

I'm working on an application that streams videos over the internet.

it works quite well when there is enough bandwidth, but when it's on edge, it's not playing very well.

I'm trying to find a way to handle this the most graceful way. I'm doing some tests with the youtube app to see how it behaves. It seems to mostly show a spinner and a black screen, or a full frame of the video with the spinner.

What callbacks and overrides are important to override in order to know when to show a spinner?

It seems I'm not getting OnError callbacks for these interruptions in the stream.